# filter a pandas DataFrame with input data from ipywidget.Text and edit result in Jupyter with ipysheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipywidgets

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to filter according to user data entered in a jupyter notebook.

The data should be entered with an ipywidget:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import ipysheet

csv_input =widgets.Text(
    value='a,b,c,...',
    placeholder='Enter the words',
    description='CSV words:',
    disabled=False   
    )
def f(csv):
    global cdf
    list_of_words=csv.split(',')
    for word in list_of_words:
        print(word)
    #HERE SOMEHOW THE CODE TO GENERATE A DF FROM FILTERING CDF BASED ON IMPUT VALUES
    # how do I pass the dataframe to this function? 


out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'csv': csv_input})
```

This input consist in a comma separated values and this should be the base for filtering the dataframe.

I created this dummy dataframe:

```
list1 = ['computer','ipad','handy','headphones','milk']
list2 = ['bread','milk','ham','chocolate','yogurth','ipad']
list3 = ['table','chair','sofa','glass','plate','bottle','java']
list4 = ['python','java','c++','julia','basic','milk','ham']

data = [list1,list2,list3,list4]
names = ['electro','food','furniture','software']
columns = ['name','data']

cdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
cdf.data = data
cdf.name = names
cdf
```

I am looking for a way to link the ipywidtext (text entry) with an output that would result from filtering the df with the words entered by the user.

NOTE: I DONT HAVE A PROBLEM FILTERING DATAFRAMES its about linking the ipywidget with the dataframe to filter it and out of the filtering result print it out with ipysheet.
The filtering consists in showing the list of names where appears any of the words entered by the user.

EDITED INFO:
When using interactive_option the function passed in get variables consisting on the output of the widgets, therefore I dont see the way to pass also other data besides the output of the widget i.e. how to pass the dataframe to further populate the ipysheet.

Documentation:
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
For instance under "Output widgets as the foundation for interact" the widgets are linked to a function that takes the outputs of the sliders, but I dont see anyway to add more inputs to the linked function.

Thanks
[image]